# Assembly x86 check if 3 values can form a triangle

Tags: assembly, x86

I have to do this problem where I have the sides and I have to check if they can form a triangle. Now I have this code but I don't know why I get both of the messages.I am new to the assembly language.

```
.model small
.stack 128
.data
    a dw 1
    b dw 20
    c dw 3
    msg1 db 'The sides can form a triangle$'
    msg2 db 'The sides cannot form a triangle$'

.code
    mov AX, @data
    mov DS, AX

    MOV AX,a
    add AX,b
    mov bX,b
    add bX,c
    mov cX,a
    add cX,c

    CMP AX,c
    JAE L1
    mov dx, offset msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    L1:
    CMP bX,a
    JAE L2
    mov dx, offset msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    L2:
    CMP cX,b
    JAE L3
    mov dx, offset msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    L3:
    mov dx,offset msg1
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
end
```

Comment: Knowing how to use a debugger is a crucial skill for any programmer. For assembly programmers doubly so IMO. Use an assembly-level debugger to step through the code operation by operation, while keeping an eye on the registers, to learn when and where it goes wrong.

Comment: Execution falls through labels.  If execution reaches the 2nd-last `int 21h`, it unavoidably falls through into L3.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed that. I have one more question. Can I jump a label or jump directly to end?

Comment: @Alexstuica120 there is no "end", the CPU doesn't stop, until you power-off the computer. There is always next instruction to execute. In DOS environment you can either call [ah=4Ch DOS service](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-4c.html) (terminate) and let DOS to deal with the powered CPU (generally good idea), or you can create infinite loop like `jmp $` burning CPU power yourself (often used by experimental bootloaders to stop execution after certain point... as there is no DOS service to call in bootloader). (you can of course jump to any memory address any time you wish)

Comment: In case you let CPU reach the point of your code at "end" and you didn't define next instruction, then the CPU will continue executing at that point, whatever is in memory stored there (probably some random stuff), i.e. most likely crashing your system. So you should always "terminate" your code when you reach "end", yourself. Either by using OS service, or by looping infinitely if you are without OS. The "end" in the source is just directive for assembler to stop assembling, but is not part of the code as something meaningful for CPU, CPU doesn't care about your source, it sees only op-codes.